# Authentication fails when establishing connection between Jenkins master and slave via EC2-plugin

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I'm having a problem in setting up ec2-plugin to work when connecting Jenkins master with "on-demand" slave ec2 instance.
This is a log from Jenkins:

```
INFO: Connecting to <EC2_PUBLIC_DNS> on port 22, with timeout 10000.
Sep 06, 2016 9:54:53 PM null
INFO: Connected via SSH.
Sep 06, 2016 9:54:54 PM null
WARNING: Authentication failed. Trying again...
Sep 06, 2016 9:55:24 PM null
INFO: Authenticating as docker-client
Sep 06, 2016 9:55:25 PM null
INFO: Connecting to <EC2_PUBLIC_DNS> on port 22, with timeout 10000.
Sep 06, 2016 9:55:25 PM null
INFO: Connected via SSH.
Sep 06, 2016 9:55:26 PM null
```

On the other hand, I'm able to connect from Jenkins master to slave and vice versa via ssh command without any problem.
Any idea what might be the issue?

Thanks in advance,
Bakir

Answer (score 0):

After long investigation, it turns out that problem was that my unix user docker-client didn't have public ssh key (from keypair) in:

```
/home/docker-client/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

but instead it had in

```
/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

In ec2-plugin config section in Jenkins, I have pem key (from keypair) specified but also I'm trying to connect to docker-client (not ubuntu).
Even though I had passwordless access between jenkins master and docker-client user, that didn't take precedence and pem key was used (without success from now obvious reason)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the SSH key you have added in Jenkins EC2 plugin is same as what's used for connecting to master instance.